# VoiceOver ignores accessibilityHint in UIBarButton

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, voiceover

I have a custom button in my Navigation Bar.

[image: Interface Builder screenshot]

It's not possible edit accessibility features in interface builder with Bar Buttons so I did it in code:

```
self.addressBookButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
self.addressBookButton.accessibilityLabel = @"Contacts";
self.addressBookButton.accessibilityHint = @"Selects a phone number.";
```

In simulator and device VoiceOver ignores hint pronouncing only label:

> "Contacts, button."

Comment: You sure the hint is supposed to be pronounced as well? (Asking cause I haven't worked with accessibility).

Comment: I don't think UIBarButtonItems' `accessibilityHint` property is used.  I couldn't get it to work, and none of the standard Apple apps have hints on the bar button items. You can try making a regular UIButton, add a hint to that, and then use `initWithCustomView:`.  (I'm not sure if it'll work.)

Comment: @LordZsolt The hint is supposed to be pronounced after a short pause.

Comment: Also: I suggest using `NSLocalizedString`.

Comment: @AaronBrager thanks for suggestion. I din't started localization yet but I will.

Comment: @LordZsolt yes I'm sure. I watched WWDC 13 video. VoiceOver did pronounced hint in custom UIView control.

Comment: If it's supposed to pronounce the hint as well, then this might be a bug. Consider reporting it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `backBarButtonItem`, use of `leftBarButtonItem` made it work for me.

I've suggested a VoiceOver implementation for a custom back button in a navigation bar for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52763178/3825084) that should interest you.