# AccessibilityHint for Back Button in Navigation Controller for VoiceOver

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

Is there any way to set accessibilityHint for back button?
I would like that voiceover read first

"Back Button" and after this Hint e.g.
"Double tap to go back to select a building screen"

I'm trying to do it that way but it's not working:

in viewDidLoad:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// back button without any text just back arrow
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                     target:nil
                                                                     action:nil];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.accessibilityHint = @"Double tap to go back to select a building screen";
```

Comment: Shouldn't you set the Title for the previous controller's navigation item? I seem to remember that it will read the label as "Select a building Back button" (or something similar)

Comment: Also, Apple's guidelines for hints recommend that you don't include the type of action and instead use the third-person singular declarative for of the verb to start the sentence. "Goes back to select a building screen."

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist - Thanks For Your comments. I updated post with code that creates my custom back button without any text (just back arrow). Please don't pay to much attention about text because text will be reviewed and maybe translated also. The above code is executed in controller with selected building (this is not the controller which You can select building).

Answer (score 1):

Just set accessibility label and not accessibility hint.

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.accessibilityLabel = @"Back Button, Double tap to go back to select a building screen";

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `backBarButtonItem`, use of `leftBarButtonItem` should be the trick.

Try the code below in your view controller that displays the back button :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "chevron"), 
                                       style: .done, 
                                       target: self, 
                                       action: #selector(goBackToThePreviousView(info:)))

    myBackButton.accessibilityLabel = "this is the back button"
    myBackButton.accessibilityHint = "this is my personal hint"

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myBackButton
}
```

Now, you have **only an arrow for the back button** and you can **add whatever desired accessibility label or hint**.