# swift-ios- Accessibility - change Voiceover read/focus order to content view first then the navigation items?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover, tab-ordering

I am designing an app with accessibility enabled. I have
a `rightBarButtonItem` on the `navigationBar` , several labels in between 
and a button located at the bottom.

I want to achieve the following behaviour :
Every time the current view is loaded, the VoiceOver focus will:

1. start from the topmost label
2. visit all labels from top to bottom
3. then, the bottom button
4. finally, rightBarButtonItem

To ensure such order, I coded in the `viewController`

```
navigationController?.view.accessibilityElements = [label1, label2, button, navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem]
```

It did ensure the read order but the focus order failed at the rightBarButtonItem. It couldn't be clicked.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Every time your current view is loaded, use the [UIAccessibilityPostNotification](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#notify-a-content-change) method to get your purpose.

There are several types of change notifications but **UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification** may be the one you're interested in.

It notifies that the whole page has changed including `nil` or a `UIObject` as incoming parameters :

- With `nil`, the first accessible element in the page is focused.
- With a `UIObject`, **focus is shifted to the specified element**.

This notification comes along with a vocalization including a sound like announcing a new page.

---

**EDIT**

I misunderstood your problem that is pretty much complicated than I thought.

If you want to have an impact on the navigation bar items, you should make the native ones inaccessible and create your own custom elements to order and/or add custom actions for instance.

Let's take your example with a label, a button and a navigation bar including a right bar button (I don't take into account a potential [back button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52763178/3825084)).

Follow the steps hereunder in your view controller :

**STEP 1** : create your outlets.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var myRightBarItem: UIBarButtonItem!
```

**STEP 2** : hide your navigation bar items so as not to listen to their vocalization.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.accessibilityElementsHidden = true
}
```

**STEP 3** : create an accessible element for the right bar button.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let rightButtonView = myRightBarItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
    let navigationBarView = rightButtonView?.superview?.superview?.superview

    let newElt = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: self.view)
    newElt.accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace = navigationBarView!.convert((rightButtonView?.superview!.frame)!,
                                                                            to:self.view)
    newElt.accessibilityLabel = "new navigation right bar button"
    newElt.accessibilityTraits = .button

    //Order your elements as you wish.
    self.view.accessibilityElements = [myLabel,
                                       myButton,
                                       newElt]
}
```

The last step consists in adding a single action [or more](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-actions) to your right bar button according to your application purpose.

Once done, you can customize with this approach and read/focus order to content view first then the navigation items as stated in your question.

This solution may be optimized but it allows to reach your goal.

Comment: I know these basics, but when and how to move focus from the bottom button to the rightbarbuttonitem in the navigation bar?.  As far as I understood, moving focus itself doesn't change the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function as an UIAccessibility extension to set the focus on any item when you load the screen, then execute your accessibilityElements

```
extension UIAccessibility {

static func setFocusTo(_ object: Any?) {
    if UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.8) {
            UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: object)
        }
    }
}
```